# Merge stay pending, status ( stuck )

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I climbed a merge, and the jobs didn’t start.
This job is in pending state and is waiting to be picked by a runner gitlab

[image]

I canceled this merge and sent another, and the same problem happened.

Can anyone tell me why this problem?

And how to solve it?

Comment: Can you write how your `.gitlab-ci.yml` file looks like? One common cause of stuck jobs is using a `tag` in your job without any runner that can handle that tag, or having multiple `tag`s with no runner that has all those tags.

Comment: I already did several merges, and none of them gave a problem, and I didn't move the .gitlab-ci.yml file. I will update the topic, and post the file.